# What's the variance of an odds ratio?

Tags: statistics

I know that 
$$\log(\hat{\psi}) \sim N\left(\log(\psi), \frac{1}{n_{11}} + \frac{1}{n_{12}} + \frac{1}{n_{21}} + \frac{1}{n_{22}}\right),$$ so what's the distribution of $\hat{\psi}$?

Note that $\displaystyle\hat{\psi} = \frac{n_{11}n_{22}}{n_{12}n_{21}}$

I tried using the $\delta$-method, and found that 
$$\hat{\psi} \sim N\left(\psi, \frac{1}{n_{11}} + \frac{1}{n_{12}} + \frac{1}{n_{21}} + \frac{1}{n_{22}}\right).$$
Is this correct?

Comment: So $\hat {\psi} $ is both log-normal and also non random (since it is a function of some constants)?